# LuaLaTeX, PSTricks and \maketitle conflict?

Tags: luatex, pstricks

The command `\maketitle` leaves a blank page before the title with PSTricks when compiling via LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\title{My title}
\author{}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I've tried with TeX Live 2021 and MiKTeX up-to-date (1/02/2022).

Comment: No problem with MiKTeX, loading `auto-pst-pdf-lua` first.

Comment: @Bernard but as far as I can see that disables the (new) lua postscript implementation

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I wasn't aware of this postscript implementation.

Comment: I opened an issue here https://github.com/zauguin/luapstricks/issues/79

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
{\let\clearpage\relax\maketitle}
```

until it may be fixed.